# net core 7, dotnet test : continue after one test failed

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit

I am using .net core 7.

From command line, dotnet test (I am using nunit) stops when a test failed.

Is there a way to NOT stop and continue with following tests ?

Thx !

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide some code to better illustrate your issue?

Typically `dotnet test` runs all tests and provides a report on which pass and which fail.

For example, on this minimal reproduction:

```cs
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void FailingTest1()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }

    [Test]
    public void PassingTest()
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }

    [Test]
    public void FailingTest2()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

When I run `dotnet test`, I see:

```
PS C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro> dotnet test
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Repro -> C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\bin\Debug\net7.0\Repro.dll
Test run for C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\bin\Debug\net7.0\Repro.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.4.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
  Failed FailingTest1 [27 ms]
  Stack Trace:
     at Repro.Tests.FailingTest1() in C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\UnitTest1.cs:line 8

1)    at Repro.Tests.FailingTest1() in C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\UnitTest1.cs:line 8


  Failed FailingTest2 [< 1 ms]
  Stack Trace:
     at Repro.Tests.FailingTest2() in C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\UnitTest1.cs:line 20

1)    at Repro.Tests.FailingTest2() in C:\Users\SeanK\Repositories\2023_01_NunitRepro\Repro\UnitTest1.cs:line 20



Failed!  - Failed:     2, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     3, Duration: 30 ms - Repro.dll (net7.0)
```